# Get recent order counts by phone number in recent 2000 documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There is orderdocuments stored in our elasticsearch. There is a field lets say phone-number in each document.

what we want to find out is phone number counts(how many times a order was received from a phone number) .

Each (i repeat each) phone numbers have made 10 million+ bookings across all our data. 
So aggregating across all the data is taking too much time. we came to a conclusion that a limit should be put because data is too much. we introduced terminate_after in the query and the response times improved to desired limit but then a new problem got introduced. If we are going to put a limit, we want to limit results from most recent 2000 documents instead of any 2000 docs.

So in nutshell we want to find out ordercounts by phonenumber in most recent 2000 documents.

How to achieve this in elasticsearch.

what we have tried so far:

- bucket sort (it applies only after the buckets are already created)
- terminate_after property in query(this does not take into account that 
   we want counts in most recent 2000 matches)
- TopNhits aggregator (This also works post the hits are calculated)

Comment: What is all our data? is it in more than one index? how many shards are in the index? how are they sharded?

Comment: All our data equals = 13 index(3 shard each), 1 index hosts around 30 million documents, they are randomly sharded